# Infinite primes of a number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. I know that to each real and to each complex conjugate pair of embeddings of $K$  there corresponds exactly one prime (equivalence class of absolute values) of $K$. How do I show that distinct embeddings give rise to distinct primes?

Many thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prime" and "absolute value" in a number field?

Comment: @Nimda: In this context a prime of $K$ is certainly understood to be a prime ideal of the associated ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Each such prime defines a discrete valuation on $K$ and hence an absolute value.

Comment: @Dune No, that's not correct. This question is about (classes of) absolute values arising from embeddings, not the ones arising from prime ideals of the ring of integers.

Comment: @anon: Are these really called "primes"? Sometimes they are called "places". Maybe it is a typo?

Comment: @Dune Different usage of terminology, sure. I more often than not have seen "places" to mean equivalence classes of absolute value. But I have seen "prime" used this way before too. Have you heard of the "prime at infinity" or seen $p\color{Red}{\le}\infty$ in subscripts of $\prod$s before? (BTW instead of calling your comment not correct I should said it's not relevant to OP's desires instead, sorry.)

Comment: @anon: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answered yet, let me have a try. But be careful: This is just an idea. I didn't check it in all details so there is no guarantee for correctness.

You already know that each complex embedding of $K$ gives an archimedean absolute value. If we find a way to assign an embedding to each (class of) archimedean absolute value, you can easily show that both mappings are inverse to each other, and the correspondence turns out to be bijective. So let $|\cdot|$ be an arbitrary archimedean absolute value.

1. Show that the restriction of $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to the usual absolute value. So without loss of generality we may assume that they coincide on $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. The completions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $K$ with respect to $|\cdot|$ yield an injective (canonical) homomorphism $\mathbb{R} = \widehat{\mathbb{Q}} \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} \widehat{K}$. Show that it is algebraic.
3. By the fundamental theorem of algebra there are only two possibilities: $\varphi$ must either be an isomorphism or $\varphi$ defines a field extension of degree $2$ in which case $\widehat{K} \cong \mathbb{C}$. The latter isomorphism is not canonical, but there are again only two possibilities (compatible with $\varphi$): If we take a root $x \in \widehat{K}$ of the polynomial $X^2+1$ we can either assign $x \mapsto i$ or $x \mapsto -i$.

Conclusion: For each archimedean absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $K$ we get a canonical embedding $K \to \mathbb{R}$ or a canonical pair of  embeddings $K \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the homomorphism $\varphi$ being algebraic? Regards

Comment: @user149343: A homomorphism $\varphi : E \to F$ between fields $E,F$ is algebraic if $F / \varphi(E)$ is an algebraic extension. So we treat $E$ as a subfield of $F$ via $\varphi$.

Comment: Here are some links: the first item is proven here (http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/antchap6.pdf, Proposition 6.2). The second item is mentioned but not proven here (http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter3.pdf, Proposition 3). In fact there is an even stronger statement: If $L/K$ is a finite extension of valued fields of degree $n$ then also $\widehat{L}/\widehat{K}$ is finite of degree $\leq n$. Certainly any $K$-basis of $L$ becomes a $\widehat{K}$-generating set of $\widehat{L}$.